# Retain hover style while navigating HTML select element's drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML `select` item that changes style when you hover over it.  However, in Chrome on Windows, this effect stops when you navigate through the select drop-down menu and off of the original location.  (This issue is not apparent in Chrome on a Mac because that uses default colors.)  How do I get the select drop-down menu to continue to trigger hover while the user is navigating it?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/LH852/2/).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942619/hover-style-remain-while-navigating-drop-down-menu) looks helpful for `li` drop-down menus, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to the `select` element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LH852/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this

```
select:focus{
    background-color:green;
    color:blue;
}
```